# What is the best algorithm to sort a number?

Tags: python, performance, optimization

So I have this document called new.txt which contains many digits of pi (see https://www.piday.org/million/) and I want to split the number into a list made out of all these digits in order. My code works but it's extremely slow, (I have tried with a less digits of pi).

```
def sort(stuff):
    for iter_num in range(len(stuff)-1,0,-1):
        for idx in range(iter_num):
            if stuff[idx]>stuff[idx+1]:
                temp = stuff[idx]
                stuff[idx] = stuff[idx+1]
                stuff[idx+1] = temp
    return stuff
                

a = []
with open("/Users/serax/desktop/new.txt", "r") as r:
    for line in r.readlines():
        for char in line:
            text = a.append(char)


print(sort(a))
```

Comment: There is no need to bubble sort. There are just 10 items - just iterate the file once and count how many times each digit appears and then print the resulting dictionary in order (the 1s first or the 9s depending on ascending/descending order). This is a very basic form of a bucket sort.

Comment: Note that you can use the fast `sorted` built-in with a `key` parameter here I think

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks, now it's so quick!

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks, but it's no fun to use built in functions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to the comments i have edited my code, here's the result.

```
thisdict = {
  ".": 0,
  "0": 0,
  "1": 0,
  "2": 0,
  "3": 0,
  "4": 0,
  "5": 0,
  "6": 0,
  "7": 0,
  "8": 0,
  "9": 0,
  }

with open("/Users/serax/documents/new.txt", "r") as r:
    for line in r.readlines():
        # print(sorted(line)) # built in function that can sort str/list/tuple (works)
        for char in line:
            for key in thisdict:
                if char == key:
                    thisdict[key] += 1

ordered = ""
for i in thisdict:
    ordered = ordered + i*thisdict[i]

print(ordered)
```

Comment: Consider using a Counter for neater code :)